# linear regression and obfuscation matrix - just not clicking for me?

Tags: matrix, matrix-inverse

Here is the basis of my question.

We have an exercise to take a data set of made up insurance claims and train a linear regression model to predict future claims; however, because it is sensitive data, we want to use an obfuscation matrix to mask the data's values. Again, seemed pretty straight forward.

Now, I "*know*" that we can multiply the matrix by the obfuscation matrix and it won't have a significant impact on the accuracy of the prediction - but when I say "know" it is because I've done some reading and testing on the subject that says this is so - due to properties of the matrix.

What I don't know is ***WHY***.

---

As part of our program, we are told properties that we can take on faith as true such as:

prediction of linear regression are given by

$a=Xw$, where $X$ is the feature matrix, and $w$ is our weight vector.

we are also told to assume that the equation for the weight vector is:

$=(^{})−1^{}$

and we are told we can use an invertible matrix to mask (we'll call it $P$) so our new feature matrix becomes:

$X'=XP$

the next step is to plug that in to the formula for our weight vector:

$′=((′)^{}′)^{−1}(′)^{}=(()^{})^{−1}()^{}$

Now is where I get lost - I am supposed to simply the right side of the equation using some properties of invertible matrices:

all invertible matrices   $^{−1}=^{−1}=$

where  $$  is an identity matrix characterized by the fact that $==$ for any matrix  $$

I'm just lost. I don't know where to start. Any input would be greatly appreciated. I've done some reading on the subject but it is just not clicking.

Comment: Hint: $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1} A^{-1}$ and $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$.

Comment: @Sycorax sorry, i'll read up on that and try to edit the original question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $\tilde{X} = XP$ for $P$ an invertible matrix, we have

$$\begin{align}
{\beta}(\tilde{X}) &= (\tilde{X}^T \tilde{X})^{-1}\tilde{X}^T y \\
&= (P^TX^TXP)^{-1}P^TX^T y \\
&= P^{-1}(X^TX)^{-1}P^{-T}P^TX^T y \\
&= P^{-1}(X^TX)^{-1}(PP^{-1})^TX^T y \\
&= P^{-1}(X^TX)^{-1}X^T y \\
&= P^{-1}\beta(X)
\end{align}$$
which uses the facts that $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$ and $(AB)^T=B^T A^T$. This should make it clear that the only difference in the coefficients compared to the usual case is a is a factor $P^{-1}$.

Whether or not this is small or a large difference in the coefficients compared to using $X$ instead of $XP$ depends on the choice of $P$.

- As an example, we would expect a diagonal $P$ with diagonal elements close to 1 to be very similar; in the case that all diagonal elements are exactly 1, then $P=I$ and it should be obvious why this special case would result in estimating the same coefficients.

However, looking at the model predictions, we see that the $P^{-1}$ factor must cancel out:

$$\begin{align}
X\beta(X) &= X\beta(X) \\
&=  XPP^{-1}\beta(X) \\
 &=  \tilde{X}\beta(\tilde{X}) \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: i think i follow you. i'm going to have to digest this for a while.